# mysql cant add wildcard in IN Operator

Tags: mysql, in-operator

I am trying to execute the following MYSQL QUERY, and it gives me an error, any ideas?

```
SELECT * FROM `cdr` WHERE `src` IN (5%,9725%,05%);
```

TIA

Comment: Use `LIKE` operator instead

Comment: first show your data. have you store data like 5% or do you want to use like ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query doesn't work because your '%' is being interpreted as the [modulo operator](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/non-typed-operators.html) which is a binary operator and as such makes your syntax invalid.

```
 SELECT * FROM `cdr` WHERE `src` like '5%' OR src LIKE '9725%' OR src LIKE '05%';
```

If you want to use the '%' character as a wild card it has to be quoted and used with the LIKE operator.

Answer (score 0):

wild card is used for LIKE clause only, IN clause uses string to compare in sql